# Return JSON Data from PHP and Ajax

Tags: php, json, ajax

In my web application just I trying to returning `JSON` data from `MySQL` database using `PHP` and `AJAX` query. This is where I follow a tutorial on internet. In case in my application it shows and error like;

> data = "↵↵↵
> ↵**Notice**: Undefined index: lymph in
> **C:\xampp\htdocs\Hospital\hospitalwebsite\test_query\fetch_count.php**
> on line **29**

**Here is my AJAX Code :-**

```html
<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $('select').material_select();

    $('#search').click(function () {
      var id = $('#test_list').val();
      if (id != '') {
        $.ajax({
          url: 'test_query/fetch_count.php', // Url to which the request is send
          method: 'POST', // Type of request to be send, called as method
          data: { id: id },

          //dataType:"JSON",
          success: function (data) {
            $('#success_mes').fadeIn().html(data);

            $('#test_info').css('display', 'block');

            $('#1').text(data.WBC);
            $('#2').text(data.lymph);
            $('#3').text(data.Mid);
          }
        });
      } else {
        alert('sdsd');
        $('#test_info').css('display', 'none');
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

**Below is the PHP Code :-**

```php
<?php

session_start();
require_once "../phpquery/dbconnection.php";

if (isset($_POST['id'])) {

    //$id = $_POST['id'];

    $stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM testing_report WHERE testing_report_id = ? AND test_id='7' ");
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $_POST['id']);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    if ($result->num_rows === 0);
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

        $medRecords = json_decode($row['testing_results'], true);
        if (is_array($medRecords) || is_object($medRecords)) {
            foreach ($medRecords as $key => $object) {

                $data["WBC"] = $object['WBC'];
                $data["lymph"] = $object['lymph'];
                $data["Mid"] = $object['Mid'];
            }
        }
    }

    echo json_encode($data);
}
?>
```

[SQL schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/33KUg.png)

Really I am appreciating if someone can help me. Thank you

Comment: please remove comment from  `//dataType:"JSON",`

Comment: where you want to show the data of `JSON`???

Comment: Hello, to be complete your question needs to provide the schema of the table "testing_report"

Comment: Please show the returned Response from Ajax.

Comment: Please check that you actually get a result from the database.

Comment: please check can you get the `JSON` response by `console.log(data);` after success function???

Comment: @KUMAR show the results on table as soon as I select something on select box

Comment: The error seems to show that in a value from `'testing_results'` that there is something without a value for `$object['lymph']`.  You could try and default it (`$data["lymph"]=$object['lymph'] ?? 0;`, but that you may need to check the results to see if they contain all of the data you are expecting.

Comment: @NigelRen what need to be do for this??

Comment: If there aren't too many rows, can you show the results of the SELECT (`SELECT testing_results FROM testing_report WHERE testing_report_id = ? AND test_id='7'`) with the id you are using.  This means we can see the data it's trying to use.

Comment: @NigelRen other data are showing well, but the `json` data in not showing

Comment: @NigelRen check the `SQL schema` please

Comment: Sorry I missed that.  I assumed it was just the database definition.  I may be able to do something (give me 5  minutes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that your data structure is split over several array elements, something like...

```
[
    {
        "WBC": "1"
    },
    {
        "lymph": "5"
    }
]
```

so each loop round the array only has 1 piece of information.  This code combines all of that data into 1 set of information using `array_merge()` and then extracts the data from the result.

I've also added `?? 0` to default the values to 0 if not present, there may be a better default value.

```
$data = [];
$medRecords = json_decode($row['testing_results'], true);
if (is_array($medRecords) || is_object($medRecords)) {
    $medRecords = array_merge(...$medRecords);
    $data["WBC"] = $medRecords['WBC'] ?? 0;
    $data["lymph"] = $medRecords['lymph'] ?? 0;
    $data["Mid"] = $medRecords['Mid'] ?? 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Mr. Nigel Ren. I am really appreciating your well defined code. It's working fine. #Stay Safe

Answer (score 0):

JQuery work file if the result be json:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#search').click( function () {
    $.ajax({
      url: "https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2",
      method: "GET",
      success:function(data)
      {
          console.log("page:", data.page);
          console.log(data);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="search">Search</button>
```

i think you have to add correct header to your result:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');
```

add this code into first line of your php page. then jQuery know result is json.

Comment: if I put `header('Content-Type: application/json');` nothing show on my application